# Existence of non trivial holomorphic function with a given property

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Does there exist a non-trivial function $f:D \rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic in the the domain $D=\mathbb{C}- A$ where $A=[-1,1]$ such that $\lim_{z \rightarrow w}{f(z)}=0 \ \forall w \in A $?

I tried to use the identity theorem for holomorphic functions to prove that $g=0$ in D where $g$ is the same as $f$ in D and zero otherwise but I wasn't able to find an accumulation point of the zeros of g in D and so I think that theorem may not be applicable in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No non-trivial holomorphic map exists. Define $$\widetilde f(z)=\begin{cases} f(z) &\text{ if }z\in \Bbb C\backslash[-1,1],\\ 0 &\text{ if }z\in [-1,1].\end{cases}$$Now, $\widetilde f$ is continuous from hypothesis. Then, one can prove that for each triangle $\Gamma$ in $\Bbb C$ we have $\int_\Gamma \widetilde f=0$, so by Morera's theorem $\widetilde f$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C$. To prove this, note that this can be done if $\Gamma \subseteq \Bbb C\backslash [-1,1]$, as $\widetilde f$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb C\backslash[-1,1]$. But if $\Gamma$ intersects with $[-1,1]$, then we can consider a sequence of triangles $\Gamma_n$ each contained in $\Bbb C\backslash[-1,1]$ and converging to $\Gamma$. So, we have the uniform convergence $\widetilde f\big|_{\Gamma_n}\to \widetilde f\big|_\Gamma$. Hence, $\int_\Gamma \widetilde f=\lim\int_{\Gamma_n}\widetilde f=\lim0=0$, so we are done in this case also.

Now, by identity theorem $\widetilde f\equiv 0$ on $\Bbb C$ .

Comment: I'm wondering how one makes it precise in the case where the triangle Gamma intersects A (in the case where it doesn't it immediately follows from Goursat's theorem)

Comment: Suppose $\Gamma$ intersects with $A$ in a line segment and lies in the closed upper half-plane, i.e. one edge of $\Gamma$ lies in $A$ and other edges are in $\text{Im}(z)> 0$, then consider $\Gamma_n$ as a vertical translation by $1/n$. That is to say, raise up $\Gamma$ by $1/n$. Similarly, you can do it for other cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes, it seems doable in any case the way you described. And how does $\Gamma_n \rightarrow \Gamma$ imply the uniform convergence you wrote? I think I can see it visualy that the convergence doesn't depend on z and so is uniform but, is that a well known result?

Comment: Yeah, visually it is clear. If you want to see this kind of argument, look at Theorem 5.5 of Complex Analysis by Elias M. Stein and Rami Shakarchi.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! One (hopefully) last question: Would it be possible to use Dominated convergence theorem for $ \tilde{f} X_{ \Gamma_n}$  to conclude that the integrals over $\Gamma_n$ converge to the integral over $\Gamma$ ? (to skip the part of proving the uniform convergence above)

Comment: Yeah, one can apply dominated convergence theorem since all $\Gamma_n$ are contained in a large compact set, and being continuous $f$ has a bound on this compact set. So, you are done.