# Why $f $ is analytic throughout $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Take from Joseph bak complex analysis

**$7.7$ Theorem**:

Suppose $f$ is continuous in an open set $D$ and analytic there except possibly at the
points of a line segment $L$. Then $f $ is analytic throughout $D$

Im not understand this theorem statement

**My attempt** : definition of analytics function said that  if $f(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$ iff there exists a neighbourhood of $z_0$ in which $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$.

My confusion is that Suppose $f$ is analytics in $D \setminus \{0\}$

Then How it is possible that  $f$ is analytics throughout $D$ as we have already taken that it is not analytics at point  $0$

Comment: no @0-thUser i didn't read that theorem

Comment: *Where* “we have already taken that it is not analytics at point $0$”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sir .... at $D\setminus \{0\}$ mean not analytics at point $0$

Comment: Almost the same  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3824957/existence-of-non-trivial-holomorphic-function-with-a-given-property/3824964#3824964 Can you complete it now? I think you can.

Comment: No. It only means that it is analytic at every point of $D\setminus\{0\}$. It says *nothing* about whether or not it is analytic at $0$.

Comment: okss... i was misunderstood @JoséCarlosSantos sir

Comment: One can prove that for each triangle $\Gamma$ in $D$ we have $\int_\Gamma  f=0$, so by Morera's theorem $ f$ is holomorphic on $D$. To prove this, note that this can be done if $\Gamma \subseteq D\backslash L$, as $ f$ is holomorphic in $D\backslash L$. But if $\Gamma$ intersects with $L$, then we can consider a sequence of triangles $\Gamma_n$ each contained in $D\backslash L$ and converging to $\Gamma$. So, we have the uniform convergence $f\big|_{\Gamma_n}\to  f\big|_\Gamma$.

Comment: Hence, $\int_\Gamma  f=\lim\int_{\Gamma_n} f=\lim0=0$, so we are done in this case also.